# DropDown GUI (resolution) issue Unity 3D

Tags: drop-down-menu, unity-game-engine

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QpuI.jpg

Check the link for details.

When I'm running my app (that contains the DropDown feature) on my Android Phone, the dropdowns that apears from DropDown menu is really small, even tiny. I tried to set resizeTextForBestFit and resizeTextMinSize/maxSize + change Rect.height of ViewPort (where the dropdowns placed) but it doesn't work. The Scroll Rect on Dropdown List controlling the size. So how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I am having troubles with setting up larger size of dropdown..A standard size of dropdown is 160 x 30 so when you click on the dropdown arrow the 3 options below (A B and C) are same size as above and all have same font size ...

But I need to use Larger size of dropdown, so when I increase the size of it to 320 x 60, and change the font size to 5O... the change does not affect the 3 options below , A B C still have original size of 160 x 30 and original font size which is now way too small ..

Comment: are you using `screen space -overlay` canvas?

Comment: hi @MXD. As you know, you **don't actually use** "code" in a graphical IDE!  The advice you often see on SO about "posting code" is as out of date as many other things on SO.

Comment: Are you using new UI or legacy GUI?

Comment: i an using the new unity ui

Comment: hi @ArghyaGhosh - you need to close out this question

Answer (score 3):

Always choose

## "Screen Space - Overlay"

and

## "Scale with screen size"

[image]

It's just one of those weird things about Unity ... 99.9% of the time you use that setting.

In the current version of Unity, **Unity screwed-up and set the default wrong**.

Only in extremely obscure situations would you use the other settings: it's a huge source of confusion that Unity have the defaults as the wrong settings.

You could have another problem but be sure to do that.

Comment: Correct! You may want to set other properties (Reference Resolution and match) based on screen resolution and height/width ratio.

Comment: Right.  A lot of hobbyists starting out with Unity don't really understand the ***reference*** concept (it's only a reference).  And the "match" concept is an outstanding part of unity's (excellent) reactive system, but it's hard to understand unless you, uh, understand it.

Comment: Well this is a key to a lot of problems when working with IOS devices as iPhone 5 has different ratio than others

Comment: yes, it's definitely a powerful and important feature of Unity - - - but also quite difficult for new programmers to understand.  BTW I guess the OP here perhaps also has other problems!  :O